# How to convert a float to a binary variable in docplex?

Tags: python, cplex, docplex

After creating a model and solving the LP with some specialized cuts, I want to solve the IP version of the problem but changing the type of certain variables. In JAVA this uses the function:

IloConversion conversion(IloNumVar var,
IloNumVarType type)
throws IloException

What is the equivalent in DOCPLEX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corresponding API in DOcplex is not documented yet, as it is not well tested enough.
This said, you can try

```
myvar.set_vartype('I')
```

To switch a variable to integer type (or 'B') for binary. This code is provided as-is for now. Le us know if this works for you.
This method accepts either variable type instances (e.g. model.binary_vartype) or one-letter string ('B', 'I', 'C', 'S' for semi continuous, 'N" for semi-integer)

Comment: Thanks for your response. The error I am getting is:----> 4     x.set_vartype(m.binary_vartype)
      5     print(x.vartype)
      6 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docplex/mp/linear.py in set_vartype(self, new_vartype)
    189         old_vartype = self._vartype
    190         if new_vartype != old_vartype:
--> 191             nlb = new_vartype.resolve_lb(self._lb)
    192             nub = new_vartype.resolve_ub(self._ub)
    193             # maybe update bounds?

TypeError: resolve_lb() missing 1 required positional argument: 'logger'

Comment: And if I try just 'B', I get: DOcplexException: Not a variable type: B, type: <class 'str'>

Comment: Which DOcplex version are you using? my answer works with the latest 2.19 code.

Comment: Thanks...that was the issue. I upgrades based on the post: https://community.ibm.com/community/user/datascience/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?GroupId=5557&MessageKey=6e031fe0-2212-4fc9-b4fa-e0fc53405503&CommunityKey=ab7de0fd-6f43-47a9-8261-33578a231bb7&tab=digestviewer

Comment: set_vartype is not in https://ibmdecisionoptimization.github.io/docplex-doc/mp/genindex.html

Answer (score 0):

In this sample, I maximize the sum of four binaries , whose sum is less than 3.5.
When I change their type to continuous, one of them is set to 0.5 and the objective is equal to 3.5

code:

```
def test_vartype():
    m = Model()
    m.environment.print_information()
    bs = m.binary_var_list(4, name='b')
    sumbs = m.sum(bs)
    m.add(sumbs <= 3.5)
    m.maximize(m.sum(bs))
    s1 = m.solve()
    assert s1
    s1.display()

    # now switch
    for b in bs:
        b.set_vartype(m.continuous_vartype)
    # m.print_information()
    s2 = m.solve(log_output=False)
    m.report()
    s2.display()
```

and the output is:

```
* Python version 3.7.7, located at: C:\python\anaconda2020.02\envs\docplex_dev37\python.exe
* docplex is present, version is 2.19.0
* CPLEX library is present, version is 20.1.0.0, located at: C:\OPTIM\cplex_distrib\cplex2001R1\python\3.7\x64_win64
* pandas is present, version is 1.0.3
* numpy is present, version is 1.18.1
solution for: docplex_model1
objective: 3
b_0 = 1
b_1 = 1
b_2 = 1
* model docplex_model1 solved with objective = 3.500
solution for: docplex_model1
objective: 3.500
b_0 = 1.000
b_1 = 1.000
b_2 = 1.000
b_3 = 0.500
```